# How to add more arguments of a function in do.call?

Tags: r, plot, gridextra, r-grid, do.call

My question is how I might be able to add more arguments to the `do.call` function.

For example, I want to draw faceted `grid` plots with `grid.arrange`, how can I add more arguments such as `ncol=3` and `main="main title"` to the command `do.call(grid.arrange,plots)`?

Comment: `do.call(fun, c(args, list(otherargs)))`

Comment: be sure to name your arguments.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

consider this list of plots,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
pl = replicate(5, qplot(1,1), simplify = FALSE)
```

you can combine it with a list of options to be passed to `do.call`,

```
do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl, list(ncol=5, main="title")))
```

Comment: threw me an error: > do.call(grid.arrange, c(pl, list(ncol=5, main="title")))
Error in gList(list(grobs = list(list(x = 0.5, y = 0.5, width = 1, height = 1,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
In addition: Warning message:
In grob$wrapvp <- vp : Coercing LHS to a list