# how to pass optional arguments to function inside do.call

Tags: r, do.call

I wish to programmatically create an array of variable names such as:

```
desired_output <- c("first_purchase_date","last_purchase_date","largest_purchase_date",
                    "first_purchase_amount","last_purchase_amount","largest_purchase_amount")
```

I believe I can do this with `do.call`, building on something like:

```
> do.call(paste, expand.grid(c("first","last","largest"),c("date","amount")))
[1] "first date"     "last date"      "largest date"   "first amount"   "last amount"    "largest amount"
```

However I can't quite figure out how to pass the `sep="_purchase_"` argument to `paste` within `do.call`.  In `?do.call` I read that

> `args` is a *list* of arguments to the function call.  The `names`
>   attribute of `args` gives the argument names.

Attempting to incorporate this, I have tried:

```
df <- expand.grid(c("first","last","largest"), 
                  c("date","amount"), 
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

do.call(paste, args = list(...=df, sep="_purchase_"))
# does not return desired output, but instead:
# [1] "c(\"first\", \"last\", \"largest\", \"first\", \"last\", \"largest\")"
# [2] "c(\"date\", \"date\", \"date\", \"amount\", \"amount\", \"amount\")"
```

What is the correct way to produce `desired_output` via `do.call`?

Comment: I think you want `do.call(paste, c(df, sep="_purchase_"))`.

Comment: also, I'm aware that this works:  `mapply(paste, df$Var1, df$Var2, MoreArgs = list(sep="_purchase_"))`

Comment: @eipi10 that works -- if you write it as an answer, I'll accept

Comment: This question is actually a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962605/how-to-add-more-arguments-of-a-function-in-do-call-in-r) although I must have been using the wrong keywords when searching

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do `do.call(paste, c(df, sep="_purchase_"))`, but maybe `apply(df, 1, paste, collapse="_purchase_")` is more straightforward.

Comment: I think it's helpful to compare `str(c(df, sep="_purchase_"))` and `str(list(df, sep="_purchase_"))`.  Both are lists, but the former is in the "flat" structure that `paste()` is expecting, rather than the nested structure the latter produces.